# mysql db and php structure to store user virtual money

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, laravel, sms

I own small sms premium gateway in my country. Now I'm rebuilding it and so question is how to organize database structure so it would be possible to withdraw money from each user account or add money ( when new sms transaction is made )

At now I have structure when I store each transaction which has value in money, lets say 1$ and also each user has his static account which is organized by user_id and money in it like this:

```
user_id money

1       15.55
```

Flow is like this:

1. transaction is made.
2. I receive charge success.
3. Then i write into database a transaction
4. and also add to user wallet money like this: money = money +1,

but i think that this structure is bad, because you need to duplicate all data, and also there is big possibility that data gets not synchronized. 
And when in user statistics i will count all his transactions there could be situation when money in transactions differs from money in his wallet. Also withdraws from user account is very difficult because I store them in separate table as "withdraw marks" and periods, so that when I am counting money i divide that period from transactions.

As I know that banks does not have static user wallets, and all money is counted every day at the end of the day, and special marks are made, but can't find any info about that.

So point me please to right direction of database structure for keeping user money so it is possible to create statistics, withdraw and add money dynamicaly.

I'm using PHP/laravel and mysql database.

**EDIT**:
As requested in comments i will post old code structure:
When transaction is made, i write a record in database:

sms_records:

```
id = 12345
transaction_id = 12345
value = 1.50 ( $ )
user_id = 10
datetime = 05.12.2013
... other columns ...
```

also I charge user wallet ( user_accounts )

```
id = 12345
user_id = 10
money = money + 1.50 ( $ )
```

User can view statistics by period ( one month period ) from day 1 of the month till last day of month. Withdraws are made in each month for previous month ( period )

When withdraw is made I insert a special mark in database:

period_marks:

```
id = 12345
payout_id => referes to bill table
start_period = 01.12.2013
end_period = 31.12.2013
period_mark = 2013-12
total = 1.50 ( $ )

( so it means that all transactions that was made from 01.12.2013 till 31.12.2013 are payed out to user )
```

and also when withdraw is made I take money from static user account:

```
UPDATE user_accounts SET money = money - '1.50' WHERE user_id = 12345.
```

I think that this structure is very difficult and wrong. With this structure it is very simple to make mistake in static user account ( user wallet ) and when you will compare your money in wallet with statistics ( all records ) it can lead to different sums between stats and static user account.

How would be better to organize this structure ?

Comment: You should give the code you wrote so SOers can help correct your mistakes and improve your coding.

Comment: As you requested question was updated with more detailed example.